# Rails 5.1 System Test Fixtures and Database Cleanup

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Are rails 5.1 system tests supposed to reset the test database with original fixture data between each test?

This is not happening for me even between completely different test classes. One of my system tests is:

```
test 'delete thing' do
  # deletes a thing from the fixture data
end
```

then I have another test that just looks to see if the thing is there

```
test 'view thing' do
  # tries to view the thing
end
```

The test passes if the "view thing" test is ran first. If the "delete thing" test runs first then when my system test tries to view the thing then it fails.

I thought Rails system tests were resetting the data just like all the other tests. Is this not the case? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this one by changing the number of workers in our `config/puma.rb` file to 0 instead of 1.

Changing

`workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 1 }`

to

`workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 0 }`

fixed the issue for us.

Comment: are you also using `preload_app!` after setting workers to 0?

Comment: and it sounds like you must be using `puma` instead of `rack_test` for your system tests? How is your `puma.config` file differentiating between your environments?

Answer (score 1):

I have just been dealing with this exact issue this morning, and I think I have figured it out.

This doc on fixtures helped me a bit: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html.

For me though, I just had to make sure i was using the ***ModelName.method*** approach when my test involved modifying data (like adding and deleting records) as this interacts with the test database and does not change your fixtures.  At first I was using the ***fixture_name.method*** for both reading and writing, and that led to unexpected results.

So for example, with a model of *Blog* and a fixture file *blogs.yml* with one record in it (hashed to key = :one):

```
test "view blog" do
  get blog_path blogs(:one).id
  assert_response :success

  *OR*
  get blog_path Blog.first.id
  assert_response :success
end
```

But if modifying, stick with the second approach:

```
test "delete blogs" do
  assert_equal 1, Blog.count
  assert_equal Blog.first.id, blogs(:one).id
  Blog.destroy_all
  assert_equal 0, Blog.count
  assert_raises(NoMethodError) { Blog.first.id }
  assert_nothing_raised { blogs(:one).id }
end

test "before_or_after_delete_blogs" do
  assert_equal 1, Blog.count
  assert_equal Blog.first.id, blogs(:one).id
end
```

Both of those should pass.

Apologies if my explanation is off base.  If that's the case, could you provide a little more context with your example?

Answer (score 0):

I use the gem database_cleaner. Not sure if that's exactly the answer to your problem.

Also this could help?
    rake db:test:prepare

Not too sure if your issue but hopefully that helps